# Sage notebook limit representation

Tags: latex, sage

In Sage notebook, I want to print the standard mathematical notation for the limit of a function.

I expect something like this:

```
f = x+1
latex(limit(f, x=0)) + '=' + lim(f, x=0)
```

to print a properly formatted 'lim x->0 x+1 = 1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

naturally, I figured it out shortly after posting the question, always seems to work that way.  here's the code from my notes-book:

```
show("NOTE: how to print lim")
# raw latex
f = (x^2-1)/(x-1)
Lf = LatexExpr(r'\lim_{x\to\infty}') + latex(f)
show(Lf)
# dummy limit
from sage.calculus.calculus import dummy_limit as lim
Lf = lim(f, x, 0)
out = latex(Lf) + "=" + latex(limit(f, x=0))
show(out)
```

Not very elegant, really wish the limit  had a better way to represent itself in unevaluated form.

Comment: Good idea - see http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/19203 I'm sort of surprised that we didn't already have a ticket open.

Comment: Thanks @kcrisman I'll take a look at making that change ticket, and see if i cant contribute the enhancement.

Comment: @Lundy thanks! this helped on another thing I was working on! many **thanks once more!  Wishes from Sweden!**